# Processing boolean expressions without a Stack?

Tags: c, boolean, expression

I'm trying to process a boolean expression that is stored as a string.
They won't have parenthesis and the only way of combining multiple conditions is using an AND and an OR.
So I came up with this rule to match them. Does anyone know of any situation where it doesn't work?

```
processCondition() {
    if next is OR {
        if state is TRUE, done // Sets state to TRUE
        if state is FALSE, process next condition // Sets state to FALSE
    }
    if next is AND {
        if state is TRUE, process next condition // Sets state to TRUE
        if state is FALSE, skip next  // Sets state to FALSE
    }
}
```

Comment: What's correct evaluation of "FALSE AND TRUE OR TRUE" ?

Comment: @Erik: From a mathematical perspective, that's broadly equivalent to `FALSE . TRUE + TRUE`, so `.` binds tighter, so the answer should be `TRUE`.

Comment: @Erik: Ah, I see.  This is an example that breaks the OP's algorithm.

Comment: @Oli: That was the idea, depending on how he wants his rules

Comment: I thought the algorithm would provide TRUE as the result?

The first one has state FALSE, and then when it sees that the next command is AND, then it skips the TRUE part.
And then when it has this FALSE state and sees the next one being OR, it processes that next one and returns a TRUE state. 
That's how I thought the algorithm works...?

Comment: @chustar: Ah, yes, sorry, I misread your algorithm pseudocode...

Comment: @chustar: When does your algorithm actually *modify* `state`?

Comment: It modifies state every time it processes a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Erik hints, the usual rule for Boolean statements is that AND takes precedence over OR. This is often formulated as follows: a Boolean statement is a sequence of *terms* chained together with ORs, and each term is a sequence of *factors* chained together with ANDs. So you need to keep track of whether you are "inside" a term, and apply AND operations only to the result for the current term, and use OR only on the result of an entire term.

So @Erik's example breaks because even though "false AND true" is false by itself, it is just one of two terms in the outermost OR, and the other term is true.